# What is the argument type deduction rule for template of template?

Tags: c++, templates

I have three functions which use template of template:

```
template <template <typename...> class ContainerType, typename ItemType>
bool has_item(ContainerType<ItemType> items, ItemType target_item)
{
    // ...
}

template <template <typename...> class ContainerType, typename ItemType>
ContainerType<ItemType> filter(ContainerType<ItemType> items, const std::function <bool (ItemType)>& f)
{
   // ...
}


template <template <typename...> class ContainerType, typename ItemType>
bool is_vector(ContainerType<ItemType> items)
{
   // ...
}
```

I supposed that compiler can deduce the argument types successfully, but it seems that the second one can not be deduced.

```
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::cout << has_item(v, 1) << std::endl;     // OK
    
    auto less_four = [](int x) { return x < 4; };
    std::vector<int> v2 = filter<std::vector, int>(v, less_four);   // Can not be deduced automatically by compiler
    
    std::cout << is_vector(v2) << std::endl;     // OK
```

([Here](https://onlinegdb.com/edibvRxSpE) is the Demo)

What is the difference between these three functions, leads to the compiler fail to deduce types automatically?

Comment: lambda is NOT a `std::function`.

Comment: `std::function` is not the type to be used always when you need to pass a callable. `std::function` is  a type to be used for type erasure. In your code it seems to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because for the 2nd one, template argument deduction for `ItemType` fails on the 2nd function parameter; implicit conversion (from lambda to `std::function`) won't be considered in template argument deduction.

You can use [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) (since C++20) to exclude the 2nd function parameter from template argument deduction. E.g.

```
template <template <typename...> class ContainerType, typename ItemType>
ContainerType<ItemType> filter(ContainerType<ItemType> items, const std::function <bool (std::type_identity_t<ItemType>)>& f)
{
   // ...
}
```

You can also add another template parameter and stop using `std::function`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I forgot that lambda is not a `std::function`. But why function pointer still not work? The non-capture lambda function should decay to function pointer in this case.

Comment: @Chun-YeLu Same reason; implicit conversion from lambda to function pointer won't be considered and causes deduction failing.

Comment: Oh I see. So there is no other method to obtain lambda function without any implicit conversion?

Comment: @Chun-YeLu You can add another template parameter for lambda to avoid implicit conversion, like `template <template <typename...> class ContainerType, typename ItemType, typename F>
ContainerType<ItemType> filter(ContainerType<ItemType> items, const F& f);`.